# Yii2 grid-view install. Unable to locate message source for category 'kvgrid'

Tags: grid, yii2

I've downloaded yii2-grid-master from [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid)

According to readme.md
I've installed composer and din this in my console:

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-grid "@dev"
```

now I try to use it according to docs. I put this in my view:

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'name',
        'pageSummary' => 'Page Total',
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-sticky-column'],
        'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-sticky-column'],
        'editableOptions'=>['header'=>'Name', 'size'=>'md']
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'color',
        'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return "<span class='badge' style='background-color: {$model->color}'> </span>  <code>" . 
                $model->color . '</code>';
        },
        'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_COLOR,
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'format'=>'raw',
        'width'=>'150px',
        'noWrap'=>true
    ],
    [
        'class'=>'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
        'attribute'=>'status', 
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'dropdown' => true,
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'urlCreator' => function($action, $model, $key, $index) { return '#'; },
        'viewOptions'=>['title'=>$viewMsg, 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
        'updateOptions'=>['title'=>$updateMsg, 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'],
        'deleteOptions'=>['title'=>$deleteMsg, 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip'], 
    ],
    ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn']
];
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'containerOptions' => ['style'=>'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
    'beforeHeader'=>[
        [
            'columns'=>[
                ['content'=>'Header Before 1', 'options'=>['colspan'=>4, 'class'=>'text-center warning']], 
                ['content'=>'Header Before 2', 'options'=>['colspan'=>4, 'class'=>'text-center warning']], 
                ['content'=>'Header Before 3', 'options'=>['colspan'=>3, 'class'=>'text-center warning']], 
            ],
            'options'=>['class'=>'skip-export'] // remove this row from export
        ]
    ],
    'toolbar' =>  [
        ['content'=>
            Html::button('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">&lt;/i>', ['type'=>'button', 'title'=>Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Add Book'), 'class'=>'btn btn-success', 'onclick'=>'alert("This will launch the book creation form.\n\nDisabled for this demo!");']) . ' '.
            Html::a('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat">&lt;/i>', ['grid-demo'], ['data-pjax'=>0, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title'=>Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Reset Grid')])
        ],
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}'
    ],
    'pjax' => true,
    'bordered' => true,
    'striped' => false,
    'condensed' => false,
    'responsive' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'floatHeader' => true,
    'floatHeaderOptions' => ['scrollingTop' => $scrollingTop],
    'showPageSummary' => true,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY
    ],
]);
```

And when I go there, I get following error:

```
Unable to locate message source for category 'kvgrid'.
```

What's wrong? Also, I didn't uploaded any souces, because I don't know where I should put it and it's not written in readme=) Also, in framework directory (vendor) I've found some kartik-v dir and tried to change kartik to kartik-v and still there wasn't propper result.Need some help.

**UPD1**
I've changed toolbar to:

```
'toolbar' =>  [
['content'=>
    Html::button('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">&lt;/i>', ['type'=>'button', 'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Add Book'), 'class'=>'btn btn-success', 'onclick'=>'alert("This will launch the book creation form.\n\nDisabled for this demo!");']) . ' '.
    Html::a('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat">&lt;/i>', ['grid-demo'], ['data-pjax'=>0, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Reset Grid')])
],
'{export}',
    '{toggleData}'
],
```

Insane Scull adviced and I receive:

```
The 'gridview' module MUST be setup in your Yii configuration file and must be an instance of 'kartik\grid\Module'.
```

I try to add to `/basic/config/web.php`
to associative array `$config`an element:

```
/*'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
            'kvgrid' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

but unfortunately I receive:

```
Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::i18n error on the whole site.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you were using internationalization or say translation function `Yii::t()` which does not have message category `kvgrid`.

Either create message category in **configuration** or use default category `app`.

```
'components' => [
.
.
.
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
            'kvgrid' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@app/messages',
            ],
.
.
.
],
```

Try this way :

```
'toolbar' =>  [
    ['content'=>
        Html::button('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">&lt;/i>', ['type'=>'button', 'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Add Book'), 'class'=>'btn btn-success', 'onclick'=>'alert("This will launch the book creation form.\n\nDisabled for this demo!");']) . ' '.
        Html::a('&lt;i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat">&lt;/i>', ['grid-demo'], ['data-pjax'=>0, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title'=>Yii::t('app', 'Reset Grid')])
    ],
```

Comment: Not really understand, where I should put. i18n property.
Added it to property of config in /basic/config/web.php and changed toolbar in view and I receive Setting read-only property: yii\web\Application::i18n error.

Comment: @SergeyScopin. add in components under `config/web.php`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the translation for `kartik-v/yii2-grid`, simply add the following to the configuration under the `components`

```
'components' => [
      'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'kvgrid' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid/messages',
            ],
      ],
 ],
```

The `basePath` should point to the location of translation messages which are by default defined at `@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-grid/messages`. You can also check out [this](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/tree/master/messages) for further details.